# Adding phonenumber field to signup form Django

Tags: python, django

When I enter the details in this form and press the submit button , I don't see the values of phoneno and otp getting saved in the database .The fields phone number and otp are not shown at all .

[SEE image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qAIm.jpg) only username is saved and the otp and phone number fields are not displayed nor saved

This is my `signup/forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Create your models here.
class allusers1(UserCreationForm):

    phoneno1=forms.CharField(label = "phonewa",max_length=10)
    otp1=forms.IntegerField(label="OTPP",required=False)

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=(
            'username',
            'password',
            'phoneno1',
            'otp1',
        )
    def save(self,commit=True):
        user=super(allusers1,self).save(commit=False)
        user.username1=self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.password1=self.cleaned_data['password']
        user.phoneno1=self.cleaned_data['phoneno1']
        user.otp1=self.cleaned_data['otp1']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

This is my`signup/forms.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import allusers1

def signup(request):

    form1=allusers1(request.POST or None)
    if form1.is_valid():
        form1.save()

    context = {
         "form1": form1,


     }
    return render(request, "signup.html",context)
```

Comment: I think you didn't include the fields phone and otp in the user model. That may be the reason  admin is not displaying the data

Comment: Can you please explain what you are saying I didn't understand anything , You want any more code?

Comment: Can you provide your `models.py` that contains the `User` model modifications too? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `User` model is the default `django.contrib.auth.models.User` that you import in the second line. This model has [predefined fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model). `otp1`and `phoneno1` are not amongst them as you can see from the docs. So when you save a `User`instance, these attributes are simply ignored.

So you have to [extend the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) like described in the docs (Django 2.0).

```
# models.py   
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class User(AbstractUser):
    otp1 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    phoneno1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)

# settings.py
settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'

# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

You won't need a special form then for the Django admin. Your own model will inherit everything Django's User model brings with it, plus your own fields / methods.